# Show date with format

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, date

I have:

```
var date = new Date();
```

and i have many formats:

```
var one = 'yy-mm-dd';
var two = 'dd.mm.yy';
var three = 'dd/mm/yy';
var four = 'mm/dd/yy';
```

Is possible to showing current date with this four formats? I know - i can use clause IF or SWITCH and set this, but maybe in JavaScript or jQuery without external libraries i can use this format as option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're also already using jQuery UI, there's a [string formatter](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate) function in the `DatePicker`.

If not, use [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do it yourself by using getFullYear(), getMonth() and getDate() and combining them as you see fit (no jquery/jquery UI required).

If you are using or can use JQuery UI you can take advantage of the [$.datepicker.formatDate](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate) method (that's the approach we took).

Your question has been asked (in a somehow different form) [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)